# Define a function pointer to be32toh() function

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm newly learned about **function pointers** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) but I couldn't define a function pointer to be32toh() or other functions of `endian.h` header.

First of all, I can do what is told in the given thread:

```
#include <endian.h>
int addInt(int n, int m) {
    return n+m;
}
int main(){
    int (*functionPtr)(int,int);
    functionPtr = addInt;    
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to do the same for a function like `be32toh()`, I'll get a compilation error:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <endian.h>
int addInt(int n, int m) {
    return n+m;
}
int main(){
    int (*functionPtr)(int,int);
    functionPtr = addInt;
    uint32_t (*newptr)(uint32_t);
    newptr = &be32toh;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile as:

```
$ gcc test.c
```

Result is as below:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:15:15: error: ‘be32toh’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   15 |     newptr = &be32toh;
      |               ^~~~~~~
test.c:15:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

What's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: `be32toh`  is a macro and not a function.

Comment: `be32toh()` is a macro on glibc, at least.

Comment: is `be32toh` a macro maybe

Comment: Thank you all, So there is no way to do it? I mean, sometimes I need to call `be32toh()` and other times `le32toh()`, without pointer I should use `if(){...}else{}` style which has a lot of redundancy.

Comment: @milad does `newptr = &(be32toh);` work?

Comment: @milad You could use wrappers, that is, you could define your own functions, called something like be32toh_func, and pass a pointer to them. Then, each of this function calls the corresponding macro.

Comment: `sometimes I need to call be32toh() and other times le32toh(), without pointer I should use if(){...}else{}` Could you elaborate? It's rarely that you take pointers to these functions, you just know which one you want to use cause you know the input format, and you _want_ the compiler to optimize it.

Comment: @AndrewCina No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica Yeah, you're right. Thank you.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm developing an ELF parser, the input file could be either Little-endian or Big-endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the problem

`be32toh` is a macro.

> how to fix it?

Just write the function yourself.

```
uint32_t be32toh_func(uint32_t a) {
     return be32toh(a);
}

....
     newptr = &be32toh_func;
```